# Getting Ubuntu to do nothing when laptop lid is closed

Tags: 20.04, power-management, systemd-logind

My cat likes to chew on my laptop's keys whenever I leave the room. Closing the laptop prevents this problem, but it logs me out and its a pain to log back in, especially when background tasks are running etc.

This is my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file where I've set all the lid switch stuff to ignore:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

I've also set `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

It seems like my settings do get respected for the first few seconds, but if I walk away for longer, then I still get logged out / suspended. Perhaps this has something to do with the `HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s` setting?

Update: I set `HoldoffTimeoutSec` to 3600 and also set `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited` to no. One of those seems to have worked, at least so far.

Answer (score 1):

If your desktop environment is `gnome`, you can try `setting->power` and modify the setting on the right panel. The settings in your configuration files may be overwritten by this settings.

Comment: I'm using unity. I already checked power settings, nothing about lid closing in there. Only power button etc.

Comment: Would check how long the suspend setting is.  Think it goes from 5 min to never.  It suspends laptop when not using.  Might also log off, if you have it set for require password on resume.